# SASS: create a clone of class without one style/property

Tags: css, sass

I have a class that participates in several selectors in several `.scss` files. In one of selectors there is `margin:0 !important;`
I want to create a clone of this class, but it should exclude `margin:0 !important;`
How is it possible to do? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sound like you have this round the wrong way. Create the class *without* the property you don't want then `extend` it to a new class *with* the extra property. Also, reconsider the use of `!important` it's rarely necessary in properly structured CSS.

Comment: @Paulie_D, I thought about this. But it is a huge system -- so I don't want to change anything(or do minimal changes) in an old class. Let's say, old class is named `X`. This way I would have to rename it to something else (let's say `Y`), remove `margin`, and then create a new class named `X` and extend `Y`. This a lot of changes...

Comment: Then the answer is... **you probably can't** without another `!important` statement to reset the margins again but you could try.

Comment: https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/4b356b00f3999cd41f0bc6ad0b9db806